# make shape in slider revolution unclickable

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, revolution-slider

My slides have a shape on the right side where title and excerpt of the post is shown. The featured image is displayed in the rest of the slide.

I don't want this shape to be clickable.
My try was this:

```
var left; 
var right; 
var totalSlides;
var shape;

revapi4.bind('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {

    totalSlides = revapi4.revmaxslide();
    left = jQuery('.tp-leftarrow');
    right = jQuery('.tp-rightarrow');
    shape = jQuery('.tp-shape');

    //make the shape unclickable
    shape.css('pointer-events', 'none');
    shape.css('cursor', 'default');
});
```

But I can still click on that part of the slide. I also tried to make the arrows left or right unclickable the same way. The arrows were displayed and clicking was like clicking on the rest of the slide. So the arrow button was unclickable, but instead I clicked on the below slide.

How can I make the the shape unclickable? Is there another way to make parts of the slide unclickable?

Comment: with pointer-events:none; click happens on whats on the neath . so if it is a clickable area it will trigger something. May you should catch the click event and kill it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after many tries, I'v found the solution.
The code in the question is already correct. In **Link & SEO** at **Link Sensibility** I had to check **back**

After that it worked. The image is still clickable and the shape is not.

[image]